# DiscordJS/MongoDB How to get bot to update value correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

So I am trying to create a function that when a command is executed, the bot looks in the mongoDB to see if the Clue1_Status is either true or false. When  it is true, the bot ends the process, but if it is false, the bot updates the status to true. I get no errors, but the 'false' doesn't get updated to true.

Here's the code:

```
const collection = db.collection('clues')

            if(collection.find({
                "Clue1_Status" : "True" })) {
                    return;
                }

            else if(collection.find({
                "Clue1_Status" : "False" })) {
                    await configDB1.updateOne({
                        Clue1_Status: "True"
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha I changed some of the code thanks to the other answer, so now it seems to work:

```
const collection = db.collection('clues')

            if (
                collection.find({ Clue1_Status: "True" }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                  return data;
                })
              )
                return;
              
              collection.find({ Clue1_Status: "False" }, async (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.error(err)
                if (data) {
                    await configDB1.updateOne({
                    
                    Clue1_Status : "True"
                    
                    })
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

[`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) will still return true even if it doesn't find anything. The correct way to write this would be:

```js
if (
  collection.find({ Clue1_Status: "True" }, (err, data) => {
    return !!data;
  })
)
  return;

collection.find({ Clue1_Status: "False" }, (err, data) => {
  if (data) {
    data.Clue1_Status = "True";
    data.save();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but one question, wouldn't that not update the "False"?

Comment: Ahh i included: ```if (err) console.error(err)``` and found that the error was:

```TypeError: data.save is not a function```

I'll try including: 
```data = configDB1.update()``` because I am trying to update an existing value? I think